# Потоки С#. Требуется имя метода,,,

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n_thread; i++)
        {
            Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Count(i, n_thread, a, b, c)));
            myThread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
```

вот метод Count

```
 public static void Count(int id, int n_thread, float[][]a, float[][] b, float[][] c)
    {

    }
```

Ругается на (Count(i, n_thread, a, b, c)

Пишет ошибку: "Требуется имя метода"

Comment: Count и то откуда идет вызов, точно в одном классе? Попробуйте указать явно `Your_NameSpace.Your_ClassName.Count` -  только подставьте ваш namespace и класс.

Comment: да, в одном классе

Comment: Конструктор Thread, принимает делегат с сигнатурой `void(object data)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n_thread; i++)
{
    var myThread = new Thread(() => Count(i, n_thread, a, b, c));
    myThread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Ругается потому, что конструктор класса Thread требует делегат ([MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.-ctor?view=netcore-3.0#System_Threading_Thread__ctor_System_Threading_ThreadStart_)), а вы передаете туда результат выполнения метода Count.